# Перевод Data в String (Swift), результат содержит лишние обратные слэши и кавычки

Tags: xcode, строки, swift

Всем привет!

перевожу `Data` в `String` таким образом:

```
let responseData = String(data: urlData!, encoding: .utf8)
```

при выводе через `print` выглядит строка так (подходящий мне вариант):

`print(responseData)` -> `"dizt7yyFGaKeHTEWDA="`

но переменная содержит это (то же самое показывать `po` в лог):

`"\"dizt7yyFGaKeHTEWDA=\""`

в чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так все верно. Чтобы отобразить кавычки надо добавить `\"`, именно поэтому `print` выводит Вам результат в кавычках.

Пример:

```
print("\"Хорошие художники копируют, великие художники крадут\" -  Пабло Пикассо")
```

Результат:

`"Хорошие художники копируют, великие художники крадут" - Пабло Пикассо`

Чтобы убрать кавычки: `string.replacingOccurrences(of: "\"", with: "", options: NSString.CompareOptions.literal, range:nil)`

Comment: спасибо за быстрый ответ, как лучше избавится от кавычек и слэшей?
потому что обрезать первый и последний символ выглядит как костыль

Comment: То есть вам надо получить ответ без кавычек? Вот так: dizt7yyFGaKeHTEWDA=

Comment: да, просто стринг,  в виде dizt7yyFGaKeHTEWDA=

Comment: отредактировал ответ. Функция ищет все кавычки в строке и удаляет их.

Comment: Спасибо,теперь с этой строкой можно работать)